# I want to align Dynamic pictureboxs with Dynamic Labels

Tags: vb.net

Here is my function that allows me to get from a webpage the image link for my PictureBoxs and the title for my labels

```
Public Shared Function getPics(website As String, pattern As String)

    Dim tempTitles As New List(Of String)()
    Dim tempTitles2 As New List(Of String)()
    Dim lestitres As New List(Of titlesclass)

    Dim webClient As New WebClient()
    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "null")
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim counter2 As Integer = 0
    Dim counter3 As Integer = 0
    Dim counter4 As Integer = 1
    Dim counter5 As Integer = 0
    Dim counter6 As Integer = 0
    'If the website happens to go offline, at least your application wont crash.
    Dim content As String = webClient.DownloadString(website)
    Dim query = From title In Regex.Matches(content, pattern).Cast(Of Match)
                Select New With {Key .Link = String.Concat("http://www.gamestop.com", title.Groups("Data").Value),
                         Key .Title = title.Groups("Dataa").Value}
    For Each letitre In query.Distinct
        'MsgBox(letitre.Link & " ======= " & letitre.Title)
    Next
    'For Each title As Match In (New Regex(pattern).Matches(content)) 'Since you are only pulling a few strings, I thought a regex would be better.
    '    Dim letitre As New titlesclass
    '    letitre.Link = title.Groups("Data").Value
    '    letitre.Title = title.Groups("Dataa").Value
    '    lestitres.Add(letitre)
    '    'tempTitles2.Add(title.Groups("Dataa").Value)
    'Next
    Dim titles = tempTitles.Distinct().ToArray() 'remove duplicate titles
    'Dim titles2 = tempTitles2.Distinct().ToArray()
    Dim titles2 = lestitres.Distinct().ToArray()
    lestitres.Clear()

    'For Each title As titlesclass In titles2
    For Each letitre In query.Distinct
        'ListBox.Items.Add(title) 'what you do with the values from here is up to you.
        Dim ImageInBytes() As Byte = webClient.DownloadData(letitre.Link)
        Dim ImageStream As New IO.MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)
        Dim MyPic As New PictureBox
        Dim MyLab As New Label


        If (counter2 > 0 AndAlso ((counter2 Mod 4 = 0) OrElse counter3 = 1)) Then

            counter3 = 1
            counter4 += 1
            If (counter2 Mod 4 = 0) Then
                counter5 = 0
                counter6 += 170
            End If
            MyPic.Location = New Point(counter5, MyPic.Location.Y + counter6)
            MyLab.Location = New Point(counter5, MyPic.Location.Y + counter6)
            If counter4 = 4 Then
                counter3 = 0
            End If


            counter5 += 200
        Else
            MyPic.Location = New Point(counter, MyPic.Location.Y)
            MyLab.Location = New Point(counter, MyPic.Location.Y)
        End If
        counter += 200
        counter2 += 1
        MyPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        MyLab.Text = letitre.Title
        MyPic.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageStream)
        Form2.Controls.Add(MyPic)
        Form2.Controls.Add(MyLab)

    Next


End Function
```

The class named titlesclass contain two elements which i will store my Link and Title in :

```
Public Class titlesclass
Public Property Link As String
Public Property Title As String
End Class
```

And My little button does all the work

```
Dim websiteURL1 As String = "http://www.gamestop.com/collection/upcoming-video-games"
    Class1.getPics(websiteURL1, "<img src=""(?<Data>[^>]*)""><p>(?<Dataa>[^>]*)<br>")
```

What i'm trying to do is to show 4 pictureboxs per row with the lables right bellow each picture , for now some labels doesn't show , some shows just in the right place and some shows very far bellow ! I tested the values i'm getting with a Message Box and it shows me the informations in the order i need , i'm not sure if i screw up in the x,y values or if it's something else ...

Edit : I can already show the 4 pictureboxes  per row , the labels also , but the Y of some labels isn't well adjusted it can go far far bellow !

Here is some pictures that will help you to understand my situation Don't mind the buttons and listboxs , it's just for the test :
My list containt a lot of pictures , so i just showed you some when the thing work kind of well , when it shows couple of rows far from the designed picture

```
http://img110.xooimage.com/files/f/a/d/picture1-5239f7c.png
http://img110.xooimage.com/files/8/f/8/picture-2-5239f7e.png
http://img110.xooimage.com/files/4/7/b/picture-3-5239f80.png
http://img110.xooimage.com/files/f/0/f/picture4-5239f82.png
```

Comment: create a integer for the row count and increment it on every multiple of 4 and then just check the row and have the position Y change by an amount times the row count

Comment: The pictures are already showing 4 per row , the labels also , but the labels shows very far even if it's the same Y of pictureboxs

Comment: far right far left could you show on picture?

Comment: I did add some pictures so you can understand better :)

Comment: Now a bit easier to understand it looks like your jumping a row

Comment: do you mind sharing the titlesclass so i can try work on it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I cleaned the way you where generating the position of the `PictureBox` by using a `row` principle and increment:

**Note:**

- **If you need space at the top to add information start the `row` count at 1 instead of 0**

**Note 2**:

- **Here the image dimensions are harcoded but you could use dynamic ones which would be more fluid. I just cleaned the positioning code not the rest.**

Replace your function by this one:

```
Public Shared Sub getPics(website As String, pattern As String)
    Dim tempTitles As New List(Of String)()
    Dim tempTitles2 As New List(Of String)()
    Dim lestitres As New List(Of titlesclass)
    Dim webClient As New WebClient()
    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "null")
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim counter2 As Integer = 0
    Dim counter3 As Integer = 0
    Dim counter4 As Integer = 1
    Dim counter5 As Integer = 0
    Dim counter6 As Integer = 0
    'If the website happens to go offline, at least your application wont crash.
    'Handle default proxy
    Dim proxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
    proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    webClient.Proxy = proxy
    Dim content As String = webClient.DownloadString(website)
    Dim query = From title In Regex.Matches(content, pattern).Cast(Of Match)
                Select New With {Key .Link = String.Concat("http://www.gamestop.com", title.Groups("Data").Value),
                         Key .Title = title.Groups("Dataa").Value}

    Dim titles = tempTitles.Distinct().ToArray() 'remove duplicate titles
    Dim titles2 = lestitres.Distinct().ToArray()
    lestitres.Clear()
    'Count Items
    Dim item As Integer = 0
    'Count Row
    Dim row As Integer = 0
    'image: 222*122
    For Each letitre In query.Distinct
        Dim ImageInBytes() As Byte = webClient.DownloadData(letitre.Link)
        Dim ImageStream As New IO.MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)
        Dim MyPic As New PictureBox
        Dim MyLab As New Label
        'x = numéro item fois largeur image
        'y = numéro de ligne fois hauteur image
        MyPic.Location = New Point(item * 222, row * 122)
        MyLab.Location = New Point(item * 222, row * 122)
        MyPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        MyLab.Text = letitre.Title
        MyPic.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageStream)
        Form1.Controls.Add(MyPic)
        Form1.Controls.Add(MyLab)
        'Bring Labels to front
        For Each ctrl As Control In Form1.Controls
            'If the control is of type label
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
                'Then bring to front 
                ctrl.BringToFront()
            End If
        Next
        'Increment the item count
        item = item + 1
        'If item is multiple of 4 or could check 4 then
        If item Mod 4 = 0 Then
            'Reset counter
            item = 0
            'Increment Row
            row = row + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Example return:

[image: games]